# Omnipay Sagepay

Tags: opayo, omnipay

I am trying to workout how to get the fraud screening result from Sagepay.

Can see there is a 'FraudResponse' however testing via the test Sagepay gateway I seem to be in the dark.

No fraud screening scores are shown when I log into sagepay is the start of the issue I think! Any way to mock these?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear what you are talking about.

The FraudResponse field is for the premium 'ReD' fraud screening service (which returns results in realtime). Sage Pay can get this working on a test basis, but will cost £££s! The T3M service (which is bundled with Sage Pay) has a delay, so the Fraud response is not returned with the transaction response.

Unfortunately, the Sage Pay test gateway is not connected to the Third Man test system, so even after the time lag, you won't get the results anyway (which have to be accessed via My Sage Pay or the Reporting API).

Comment: Mostly what Rik said.  I have no experience with Sagepay directly but I have worked extensively with other gateways that do fraud scoring.  All of the fraud scoring is handed off to an external third party, companies like Third Man http://www.cnpfraudprevention.co.uk/ These companies charge money for their services on a per transaction basis, and so test transactions will usually not be scanned because it costs the gateway company (Sagepay) money to do that. In any case, test transactions are always fraud because they use fake card numbers.